# When reach top 680px then add css style to div

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I need to add this style in below script.

```
.logo-top{margin-top:0;}
```

So when reaching top 680 some div gets visible (which works great) but I also need to have logo-top to have no top margin when reach that point.

But how?

### EDIT

I have modified the script a little with the input I got from below.
**This works, only would like to have the logo-top animate from top 10px too -6px and back.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var startY = 680;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    checkY();
  });
  function checkY(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
      $('.fixedDiv').slideDown(400, function(){
        $('.logo-top').css('marginTop', -6);
      });
    }else{
      $('.fixedDiv').slideUp(400, function(){
        $('.logo-top').css('marginTop', 10);
      });
    }
  }
  checkY();
});
```

Comment: `$('.logo-top').css('margin-top', '0')`? (Of course, it would be better to use a class, but that’s the gist of it.)

Comment: missed your comment, will try that in combined with PHPglues version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var startY = 680;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    checkY();
  });
  function checkY(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
      $('.fixedDiv').slideDown(400, function(){
        $(this).css('marginTop', 0);
      });
    }else{
      $('.fixedDiv').slideUp();
    }
  }
  checkY();
});
```

Comment: Thanks allot PHPglue, one more thing, would like to have the logo-top animate from top 10px too -6px and back, any clue how to add the animation on the logo-top?

Comment: Use something like `.animate({marginTop: '-6px'})`. This is, of course, another question. Ask away.

Comment: Hmm, didn't work, $('.logo-top').css('marginTop', -6); needs to be: $('.logo-top').animate({marginTop: '-6px'}) ?